# IF equals something then show output in PHP

Tags: php, variables

Ok I'm not a PHP editor by default I can do a bit but I am struggling witht his simple variable. I want to display something if the value isnt set to null. The output is run by a function i think, its a catgory for a listing so it would say something like:

WHATS ON: Music, Dance, Trance

Now if there isnt a category set it just says 'WHATS ON:' where as I dont want anything to show if there isnt a category set. Heres the output to display the 'WHATS ON' and category string:

```
$featured_event .= "<p class=\"complementaryInfo\"><b style=\"color:#74c1df\">WHATS ON:</b>".system_itemRelatedCategories($event->getNumber("id"), "event", true)."</p>";
```

and heres my variable attempt:

```
if (system_itemRelatedCategories($event->getNumber("id"), "event", true) == "") {
$featured_event .= "<p class=\"complementaryInfo\"><b style=\"color:#74c1df\">WHATS ON:</b>".system_itemRelatedCategories($event->getNumber("id"), "event", true)."</p>";
                }
```

If you need any more info please ask, I hope this is enough to give you an idea of my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code and proofread your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theory is almost correct. The only issue is that you are telling it to show "What's on" ONLY if there is nothing on.

Change your `==` to `!=` and it should work fine. Or just drop the `== ""` entirely since any non-empty string will be truthy.

Personally, I'd further optimise it to:

```
if( $events = system_itemRelatedCategories($event->getNumber("id"),"event",true))
    $featured_event .= "<p class=\"...\"><b...>WHATS ON:</b> ".$events."</p>";
```

This avoids calling the same function twice.

Comment: I removed my answer since it was simply not correct. Don't know where i left my brain today. Thx for the hint though. +1 for optimizing the code.

Answer (score -1):

Use empty() function - if variable is not set or is empty then it returns true

```
if (!empty(system_itemRelatedCategories($event->getNumber("id"), "event", true)))
```

Comment: Since when is a function call a variable?